# Can I make a cross-contract call with constructor (function with "#[ink(constuctor)]" attribute) in ink! contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, openbrush

I've been trying to implement cross contract calls in constrcutor but somehow I can't seem to make it right. Is the following code executable?

```rust
#[openbrush::contract]
pub mod contract {
  #[ink(storage)]
  #[derive(Default, Storage)]
  pub struct LpToken { ... }
  ...
  impl LpToken {
    #[ink(constructor)]
    pub fn new(token: AccountId) {
      # here!!
      let base_name = PSP22MetadataRef::token_name(&token);
      let base_symbol = PSP22MetadataRef::token_symbol(&token);
      let decimals = PSP22MetadataRef::token_decimals(&token);
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I could not find any docs on cross-contract calls in constructors. I would appreciate your help in this matter.

Comment: should be correct, did you run into some problem with this code?

Comment: Do you get an error at compile time or at runtime? If at runtime: What does the Contracts UI display as an error?

Comment: Code looks ok, but full code would be better to understand your issue. Do you have one `message` call and does your constructor return the contract instance?

Answer (score 2):

With the given information it's not possible to answer the question at a level of detail that will help you. You should provide the information that people asked for in the comments, then we can help you properly.

That being said, the high-level answer is: yes, you can make a cross-contract call in a constructor.